# Error accessing to Outlook attachments by IMAP with Javamail in Android

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I'm using the JavaMail 1.5.5 to access to email accounts in my Android applications. 
When I try to access the attachments of an Outlook account by IMAP protocol, the size of the file is always displayed as 2 byts. And the inputstream used to download the file are always empty.

Using this same envoriment with a Gmail account, all are working fine.

I'm saving the attachment file with this method:

```
private File downloadMimeBodyPart(MimeBodyPart part) throws IOException, MessagingException {
    // File Name
    String currentFileName = EmailUtils.decodeString(part.getFileName());

    // Allocate the file for download
    String mediaPath = FileUtils.getAvailableStorageCacheDir(part.getSize());

    // Inform that the SDCard don't have enough space for this download
    if (mediaPath == null) {
        throw new IOException("Not enouth file space for download this attachment");
    }

    File f = new File(mediaPath + currentFileName);
    part.saveFile(f);

    return f;
}
```

Some one knows this bug?

Comment: What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?